# How to substitute FALSE with N and TRUE with Y in one column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, combine

What formula can I use in an Excel column where I want FALSE to be N and TRUE to be Y? Data is imported from SharePoint Task List to Excel for a project completion report. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
IF(A1 = "TRUE", "Y", "N")
```

Put this in a column next to yours, then paste the results over the original column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Find and Replace. CTRL + H is the shortcut for Find and Replace.

Select the column. Write True in the Find box and Y in the Replace box. Now press Replace All. Repeat the process for False.